# Error using jsbeautifier in python with unicode text

Tags: python, unicode, js-beautify

I use the following code to beautify a js file (with jsbeautifier module) using python (3.4)

```
import jsbeautifier

def write_file(output, fn):
    file = open(fn, "w")
    file.write(output)
    file.close()

def beautify_file():
    res = jsbeautifier.beautify_file("myfile.js")
    write_file(res, "myfile-exp.js")
    print("beautify_file done")

def main():
    beautify_file()
    print("done")
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The file contains the following contents:

```
function MyFunc(){
  return {Language:"ÐœÐ¾Ð²Ð°",Theme:"Ð¢ÑÐ¼Ð°"};
}
```

When I run the python code, I get the following error:

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 43: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone guide me as to how to handle unicode/utf-8 charsets with the beautifier?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you need to update the module, or go back to using python2. The module I found https://github.com/coryalder/js-beautify, claims to work for python2 and unicode...

Comment: Thanks, it did work ok in python2 without changes mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without a full stack trace but it looks like jsbeautify isn't fully Unicode aware.

Try one of the following:

1. Decode js file to Unicode:

   ```
   with open("myfile.js", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as myfile:
       input_string = myfile.read()
       res = jsbeautifier.beautify(input_string)
   ```

   or, if that fails
2. Open file as binary:

   ```
   with open("myfile.js", "rb") as myfile:
       input_string = myfile.read()
       res = jsbeautifier.beautify(input_string)
   ```

In addition, you may run into issues when writing. You really need to set the encoding on the output file:

```
file = open(fn, "w", encoding="utf-8")
```